# Is this a sufficient condition for joint normal distribution?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I have a random vector $\boldsymbol{Z}$, if I can prove that for $\forall \boldsymbol{\lambda} \neq \boldsymbol{0}$ where $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ is a fixed vector, not a random vector,

$\boldsymbol{\lambda}^{\text{T}}\boldsymbol{Z} \sim N(0, \boldsymbol{\lambda}^{\text{T}}\boldsymbol{C}\boldsymbol{\lambda})$

where $\boldsymbol{C}$ is a positive definite matrix. Can I establish accordingly, that

$\boldsymbol{Z} \sim N(\boldsymbol{0}, \boldsymbol{C})$

?

Answer (score 4):

Just to slightly expand on the existing answer: you can see that it is indeed true as an immediate consequence of Bochner's theorem. Also, Gaussian measures on infinite-dimensional spaces are actually *defined* in this way. (A measure is Gaussian if and only if its push-forwards under continuous linear functionals are all Gaussian.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes assuming $C$ is positive semi definite. This is an alternative definition of the multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: That $C$ is positve semi definite follows from the assumption. One has to allow variance $0$ for a normal distribution (which is then a Dirac measure).

Comment: I forgot to mention that $\boldsymbol{C}$ is positive definite. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Also, is there any reference or proof for this?

Comment: @YuchenXie off the top of my head I don't know a link. But one technique is to write down the moment generating function and use the uniqueness theorem of moment generating functions.

Comment: @fushsialatitude Thanks you very much for the hint, I will look for further information based on it.

Comment: A quick proof is by Fourier transformation.